# Creating latex files from the data stored as excel

Tags: pdftex, pdf, excel

I have an excel file containing five columns which include questions and four options. These questions are written using latex tags. Is there any way to automate the process of creating a pdf file from this data such that question and options are displayed properly.

Comment: If in stead the data is stored as csv then you can have a look at the datatool package

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have written such an automation for LibreOffice calc and the process basically is to export the data into a CSV file and then include these CSVs using something like `pgfplotstable`.

The program I have written takes care of exporting the LibreOffice Calc data into CSVs from which point on LaTeX can take over. As Excel uses a different file-format the same program won't work for you though. But if you can automate the CSV export in some way, then this would be rather straight forward.

In your specific example I have the impression that you are writing some text into Excel that you want to typeset in LaTeX. Therefore you probably don't want to use `pgfplotstable` but rather something like `datatool` which has been mentioned in the comments.

Alternatively you can semi-automate the process by using something like https://www.ctan.org/pkg/excel2latex or http://excel2latex.com/ to convert your Excel data into a LaTeX table.